# Can a finite dimensional vector space have dim(V) = dim(null) + dim(range) if dim(range) = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is a linear operator. Then does there exist a vector space $V$ such that $dim(V) = dim(null) + dim(range)$ if $dim(V) = 1$, $dim(null) = 1$, and $dim(range) = 0$?

I am trying to think of a reason why this isn't possible, but not really getting anything. It seems like a simple question to answer, but I am struggling on coming up with something :(

Comment: If the dimension of the range is 0, it implies the operator only maps to 0 (i.e. the 0 operator). That is the operator you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

By linearity of $T$, if the dimension of its range is zero, it necessary is 0, and your condition trivially satisfied.

Comment: I am afraid your question doesn't make sense.  A "vector space" **doesn't have** a "null space" or "range".  Those words apply to a linear transformation between two vector spaces.